# Problem connecting to MySQL from ASP in IIS

Tags: mysql, iis-7, asp-classic

I have a ASP application running on a IIS7 server on Windows Vista Home Premium (developing environment). The application has an ASA file to configure connections to the database:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript RUNAT=Server>

Sub Application_OnStart
    Application("db") = 2
    Application("dbconnect") = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Port=3306;Option=0;Socket=;Stmt=;Uid=root;Pwd=root;CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS=1;Database=appadmin;"
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

Then, requests are handled in asp pages, which first load configuration with the following code:

```
Session("configid") = 1
dbConnect = Application("dbconnect")
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open (dbConnect)
sql = "select * from settings where configid = "&Session("configid")
Set RS = ExecuteRecordset(sql)
...
```

Everything seems fine, however, on any request to the site, it logs the following error:

```
|11|80004005|[Microsoft][ODBC_Driver_Manager]_Data_source_name_not_found_and_no_default_driver_specified 80
```

Opening a command prompt and running "mysql -uroot -proot -D appadmin" connects to the database without problem.

Any ideas as to what may be causing the problem?

Comment: Sorry to bump and old question, but is there a solution for this? I have same problem with IIS 7 and MySQL 5.5 I try drivers MySQL ODBC 5.1 and 3.51

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 2):

My connection string look like this

```
ConnectionString="Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;
Database=MyDB;User=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;Option=3;"
```

Looks like yours are missing the user and password and have Option=0 instead of 3